# Use sharepoint resource keys in custom application page

Tags: localization, resource-files

I have a custom application page (apsx) with an `<asp:Label>` and i want to display a localized message in the label. I want to use an existing sharepoint resource key

**MyPage.aspx**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="MyLabel" />
```

**MyPage.aspx.cs**

```
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MyLabel.Text = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:????????;", "??", (uint)Web.Language);
}
...
```

The problem is that i do not know the resource key (that's the ??? for), but only the translation. I have looked in every file at both `C:\...\14\Resources` and `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources` directories but no luck to find the resource key for the translation.

Is Sharepoint uses another directory for resources? How can i get the resource key? Is there any list with the resource keys existing in Sharepoint?

Comment: What resource label are you searching?

Comment: do you use SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Yes i use SharePoint 2010. I have the message (translation) `The value of this field is not a valid number.` that is the message displayed when you try to add a non number value in a number field. What i am looking for is the resource key of this message

Comment: why don't you have your own resources?

Comment: One reason is that i don't want to rewrite the same messages again. It's not just one. Other reason is that suppose you have a task list, i want to take the status localized.